# Blank red screen after login

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

After login into Ubuntu 12.10, I see only a red blank screen.